# How can I use custom classes in chapter titles with Asciidoc epub3 converter?

Tags: css, asciidoc, asciidoctor, epub3, asciidoctor-epub3

In the adoc file I define a chapter header like:

```
== [big-number]#2064# Das Spiele-Labor
```

For HTML that translates to

```
<span class="big-number">2064</span>
```

For the epub-Version, converted with asciidoctor-epub, apparently the class is omitted. The code line in the converter.rb:

```
<h1 class="chapter-title">#{title_upper}#{subtitle ? %[ <small class="subtitle">#{subtitle_formatted_upper}</small>] : nil}</h1>
```

(/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/asciidoctor-epub3-1.5.0.alpha.7.dev/lib/asciidoctor-epub3/converter.rb)

How can I get the class information over to the chapter-title to format the first number in a special way?

Or is there another way to solve this? (The first number of the chapter title should be large and CSS hasn't got a 'first-word' attribute)

Comment: If you just want the number, there is a `:first-letter` selector in CSS. Alternatively you can wrap the first word in a span or include it via a `::before` pseudo-element.

Comment: It's not a digit, it's a four digit number. That would need a :first-word selector. For the ::before element I think I would have to change the code of the epub generator, and that's not what I want to do first ;-)